# Java Generics: unbounded wildcard generalization not working past second level

Tags: java, generics

I guess this is a very confusing title, but I don't know what else to call - probably answered somewhere as well, but I couldn't find anything. Take this example:

```
List<Class<? extends Integer>> myList;
void foo() {
    bar(myList);
}
void bar(List<Class<?>> a) { /* ... */ }
```

It doesn't compile (not applicable arguments, it says). If I remove the bounding it works fine:

```
List<Class<?>> myList;
void foo() {
    bar(myList);
}
void bar(List<Class<?>> a) { /* ... */ }
```

`Class<? extends Integer>` is just more specific than `Class<?>`. How come it stops working? Note that this problem is only in the second level generics. If there wasn't a List, just `Class<? extends Integer>` and `Class<?>`, it works as well. But it seems to stop working when the generics is two ore more levels deep. Any reasons/workarounds/etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `List<B>` is not a subtype of `List<A>` even if `B` is a subtype of `A`. Therefore, `List<Class<? extends Integer>>` is not a subtype of `List<Class<?>>` even though you can assign a `Class<? extends Integer>` object to a `Class<?>` variable. Just consider that in `bar`, it would be legal to invoke `a.add(Object.class)`, as `Class<Object>` is a subtype of `Class<?>`.

You therefore want to extend the `bar` argument type to `List<? extends Class<?>>`.

Comment: Nice, it works that way! And I guess it makes some sort of sense in the end...